# Walk in with me - what am I?

Tags: riddle

> Walk in with me, my hold is steady.
>
> If I'm right, you'll get off well early.
>
> My partner's waiting, we have to run;
>
> In your hands are all my twelve children.

What am I?

Hint:

> When you "go by me" , you are not driving.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker. Hopefully the idioms make sense ...

Comment: I think lines 1,2, and 4 work with the answer posted by @LearningPhase but not sure I get line 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct answer is:

> a foot

```
Walk in with me, my hold is steady.
```

> You walk with your feet, and they hold you steady.  [You can also have a Foothold on something]

```
If I'm right, you'll get off well early.
```

> You can get off on the right foot.  [You can also have an [Early Foot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/early%20foot), in a race.]

```
My partner's waiting, we have to run;
```

> When partnered with the left, you can run.  [You can wait on hand and foot, too, but that needs a hand.]

```
In your hands are all my twelve children.
```

> A foot has 12 inches. You can hold a ruler in your hands.  [A Stretch: 3 [Hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_%28unit%29) are 12 inches long.]

```
When you "go by me" , you are not driving.
```

> To go by foot is to walk.

Answer (score 3):

> Second hand of clock (smaller tick/hand)

Please refer explanation given below:

Walk in with me, my hold is steady.

> It works steadily.

If I'm right, you'll get off well early.

> If second hand works perfectly, the minute hand works perfectly and perfect time gets updated.

My partner's waiting, we have to run;

> My partner (minute hand of clock) is waiting for 60 seconds to get completed.

In your hands are all my twelve children.

> the 12 numbers on clock.

Comment: That's not the correct answer either.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

> Shoes : they never skid. If the shoes are not tied too tight, you can take them off with untying the laces. We tie the laces with our hands.
>  When we go by foot with shoes on we are not driving we are walking.

Comment: Use spoiler tags like I just edited in. I know it's your first post, so it's no biggie. But some people like to go through and solve things on their own. Even if the puzzle is already solved. And even though I think your answer is probably right. You're supposed to explain each hint that stood out to you.

Comment: @Z.Dailey will keep this in mind moving forward. Thanks for the guidance. Also as you stated in your above comment in the question I got 1, 2 and 4 lines which pointed to my answer but don't have any idea about line 3

Comment: Add the explanation for 1, 2, and 4 and how they pointed you to the answer in your post.

Comment: This is not the answer I was thinking about, but it's a nice idea!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not, but you could be:

> A wristwatch

Walk in with me, my hold is steady

> A wristwatch is strapped on

If I'm right, you'll get off well early

> If the hour-hand is right, it's only 3:00, which would be an early leaving time for most day jobs

My partner's waiting, we have to run

> I would say a wristwatch's partner could be a Fitbit (pedometer), which would be a good combination for going on a run (how far and how long did it take)

In your hands are all my twelve children

> The twelve hours of a watch face

Comment: Nice try, and a good match with quite a few of the clues, but there's better. Do not focus on time though, it's a dead end.